# set focus on the an html control after postback

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, postback

I am using a form in ASP.NET where dropdownlists cause postback. **I want to set focus back to a specific textbox control after postback occurs.**

I tried calling

```
SetFocus(TextBox1.ID)
```

but my focus is not changing. I called this function in Page_Load. I ran the app in debug mode and verified that TextBox1 is not null and refers to the correct textbox.

By the way TextBox1 is an html control. Here is the markup

```
<input type="text" id="TextBox1" runat="server" />
```

Here is the dropdownlist that causes postback

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdown_finance runat="server"
                         OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropdown_financer_SelectedIndexChanged"
                         AutoPostBack="true">

                         <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Father / Husband</asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem>Mother</asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem>Specify information of financer</asp:ListItem>
                     </asp:DropDownList>
```

I just want to set focus to my textbox. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

put it inside the callback method like this

```
protected void dropdown_financer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // other codes

   TextBox1.Focus();
}
```